# EC2-like virtualisation platform with non-RDP access

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualization, hyper-v, remote-desktop, cloud

I'm looking into setting up a few small VMs. The trouble is the software I intend to install on them (Cisco VPN Client) blocks out networking (other than to the target VPN destination...) with no workaround.

This means that Remote Desktop or other methods of connecting to VMs that go via the Internet (e.g. GoToMyPC, LogMeIn) are a non-starter. What I'm really looking for is an EC2-like platform but which gives direct access to the VM through (for example) Hyper-V Manager. Sadly the only way they all seem to offer to remote control the VMs is direct access via Remote Desktop, whereas I need to be one layer above that (if that makes sense).

A viable alternative would be to run virtualisation software within a Windows EC2 instance; obviously hardware virtualisation is impossible but I wonder if there are any software virtualisation platforms that could be run and that would work.

Does anyone know if something like this exists/is possible?

Thanks!

C

Comment: Have you tried Azure? MS said it runs already on 2012 R2 - and 2012 R2 Hyper-V new feature is Host level RDP, i.e. you can connect to the VM with RDP but to the machine - like Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: I haven't actaully - I took one look and saw it gave RDP connection instructions. I'll definitely take a closer look!

Comment: I Just know that 2012 R2 is out now as preview - supposedly Azuerea already uses it - and they got rid of Hyper-V manager and moved to RDP for that. Can not say I do not like it (makes things easier, definitly).

Answer (score 6):

You're asking the wrong question...

The Cisco VPN client can support [split-tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling)...

That's what allows access to a local LAN *and* the tunneled VPN network at the same time, rather than killing all non-protected VPN traffic.

This would be a configuration change on the VPN endpoint (firewall) that you're connecting to. If that system is not under your control, contact the firewall's administrator and request this functionality.

The answer to this lies with your VPN configuration and not the feature-set supported by a particular cloud hosting solution.

Comment: +1 was just about to start typing about split tunnels as I was reading the post